# Dynamic params calling window opener

Tags: javascript

This doesn't seem to work:

```
func = "getProductListings"; 
params = "{'user_id':1234,'short':true}"; 
window.opener[func](params);
```

can someone check my code please?

Comment: Paul, where is the definition of the actual function? what's not working? what's the error you're getting? Are you using firebug/element inspector?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work at the opener end (sorry for not being clear). This code alerts "undefined". 
function getProductListings(oArg) {
        alert(oArg.user_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points you might want to check out:

- When a window is opened from another window, it maintains a reference to that first window as `window.opener`. If the current window has no opener, then this method returns `NULL`. Is there a parent window? ... And does it have a `getProductListings` function defined?
- Does your `getProductListings` function expect an object as the first argument? In that case, you'd want to remove the double quotes from the `params`:

  `params = {'user_id': 1234, 'short': true};`

Comment: Yes, it all follows through to the opener fine, and even reaches the function in the opener, but the following code alerts "undefined": function getProductListings(oArg) {
        alert(oArg.user_id); }

Comment: @Paul: Yes, that it's because of the second point. You do not want `params` to hold a string, but an object. Simply remove the quotes that wrap the definition.